# How to change Django updateview date display format?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm using Django `generic updateview`, and when I edit an object I get an input with this format:

```
2016-10-26 00:00:00
```

but I want to get

```
26/10/2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed in my settings.py the LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us' to LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-au' as I am in Australia. And all the dates changed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the standard date format in your settings ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/settings/#date-format)).

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
```

Make sure to take care of the USE_L10N as mentioned in the docs.